# Relative path in Visual Studio 2017 during Run

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, relative-path

I want to open a file in VS2017 with C++ by using fopen and relative path. But every try I got an error so I look at the absolute path of my relative input:

```
string ExePath() {
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    return buffer;
}

string AbsPath(string path) {
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];  strcpy_s(buffer, path.c_str());
    char buffer2[MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathName(buffer, MAX_PATH, buffer2, NULL);
    return buffer2;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Application\t " << ExePath() << "\n";
    cout << "\\data.dat\t" << AbsPath(".\\data.dat") << "\n";
    system("Pause");
}
```

I got the output:

> Application      C:\Users\User\source\repos\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe
>
> \data.dat        C:\Users\User\source\repos\Project1\Project1\data.dat

My Application is located in .\Debug\ and my relative path points to \Project1. Do I made an error?

Comment: Visual Studio usually sets the default "current directory" to the *project* path, not the path to the executable. No error, it's just that your guess was incorrect.

Comment: Relative paths are always relative to the current working directory, not to the directory where executable is located.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working directory vs output path in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321089/working-directory-vs-output-path-in-visual-studio)