# Path.Combine not working / cannot get working directory

Tags: c#, path, working-directory

I've set my working directory to a folder called "working" within my solution (by right-clicking solution->debug->set working directory). I've created a file in that folder called appSettings.xml.
I want to get the path of that xml file and put it into a variable, I've tried the following code but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?:

EDIT: the problem appears to be that my working folder is ...bin\debug even though I've set it to the correct path in the properties. How do I set it to a different directory?

```
string settingsPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appSettings.xml");
```

Comment: have you double checked the output of PathCombine against your files location?

Comment: It won't show me what the output is. I'm getting "cannot obtain the value of the variable because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away"

Comment: is it a Console application? also: chances are you want that `appSettings.xml` at the location of your executable rather then where the actual workspace is right? because then this is not how you would do it. (`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.Substring("file:///".Length)` gives you the executable path)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check, `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is exist or not

```
if(Directory.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
{
  //This will write CurrentDirectory path on console
   Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); 
  //If exist then check for Path.Combine()
}
```

> Note : Current directory is distinct from the original directory,
>   *which is the one from which the process started*

Most of the time it is directory of your bin folder

You can set CurrentDirectory by passing parameter to your function

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"c:\program files\");
```

Comment: I have right clicked on solution->debug->and changed the working directory there so that it points the the "working" folder in my solution.

Comment: Have you marked your xml file for Copy to Output Directory as **Copy Always**.
*Xml file -> right click -> properties -> Copy to Output directory set as Copy always*

Comment: entering the code above tells me that the directory exists, but I'm not sure how to find the exact path. Surely it should be the directory I selected in properties/working directory?

Comment: Thanks, I can see the problem now. The problem is that GetCurrentDirectory is still pointing to the bin\release folder instead of the "working" folder even though I've selected it as the working directory in the properties. How do I make sure "working" is the working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Check Directory as earlier answer should tell if the directory exists.
Don't know if you've copy and pasted the file name in your question. In that case, you've spelled the filename wrong since it's spelled with 3 x T where you mention the filename and 2 x T in your code.
Could be easy to miss, think everyone has done that once or "twice".

Try to take the path as strings to check that the code can find your file.

```
if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(filedirectoryPathAsString, fileName))
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem appears to be that my working directory is set to ...bin\debug instead of to the "working" folder in my solution. I'm not sure how to set my working directory to the correct one. I've selected it in the properties window under "working directory" but that doesn't appear to be working

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the Edited question.
You can change the output directory by `Right click on project -> Properties -> Build -> Output -> Output path`

Also look into this solution to see the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27322567/4731319